# How to list only OpenStack orphan instances?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-nova, orphan

Is there an any command can be listed down only the ***orphan instances*** instead of list down all the instances of OpenStack using command `nova list` ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer:

nova hypervisor-servers  will show the orphaned instances, but only by using nova show  on each server and comparing tenant_id with known project_ids from openstack project list. If no match, then use nova delete  to remove the orphaned instance(s)

in the [ask.openstack.org site](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/94386/how-to-check-whether-is-orphan-instance-and-delete-orphan-instance-with-python/), so just sharing it in case it helps